# Jquery, event when reverting?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I am using Jquery Ui's draggable and the revert option.

Is there a way to detect whether the element is reverting?

```
$(function() {
$("#draggable").revert(function(){
alert('the div is reverting');
});

});
```

Ive seen

```
   revert:function(){
alert("");
}
```

However it seems to set the revert position to where the mouse has been released.

Right now, the option i seem to have is to use mouseup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's actually interesting that that works at all.  I was unable to find any mention of it in the documentation.  It appears that the function is called and if `true` is returned it will revert if `false` then it will not revert.  Since you have no return at all, it is treated as `false`.

So, if you were using the revert option with `true` as the value (which means, always revert), then you can simply add a return statement to your function:

```
$(function() {
    $("#draggable").revert(function(){
        alert('the div is reverting');
        return true;
    });
});
```

If you were setting revert to `invalid` however, I'm unsure how you could do this.

And since it's not documented, use at your own risk I guess.

**EDIT:**  I looked into it a bit more and apparently an agument is passed to the function which is the droppable it was dropped on, and false if no droppable.  So technically you could emulate `invalid` like this:

```
$(function() {
    $("#draggable").revert(function(droppable){
        alert('the div is reverting');
        return !!droppable;  // might just be able to return droppable but I think this is safer
    });
});
```